# Coercive function and the existence of a ball

Tags: real-analysis

I have a continuous function $V:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which  is coercive that is $$V(x)\rightarrow +\infty, ~|x|\to+\infty$$

How to prove that for each $\eta>0$ there exists $R>0$ such that $$\frac{1}{V(x)}\leq \eta,~ |x|>R$$

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much by definition. The condition

$$\lim_{|x|\to \infty} V(x)= \infty$$

says that for each $N>0$, there is an $R>0$ such that $|x|\ge R$ implies $V(x)>N$.

So given $\eta>0$, take $N = \displaystyle \frac{1}{\eta}$.

Comment: That's all ? ??